# Calling a method from createReceive in Akka

Tags: java, akka

How does following code work in Akka:

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .match(DeviceManager.RequestTrackDevice.class, this::onTrackDevice)
            .match(RequestDeviceList.class, this::onDeviceList)
            .match(Terminated.class, this::onTerminated)
            .build();
}
```

onTrackDevice is another method in same class and it takes an input. Here it is invoked without any argument. I understand that passed message would be passed to onTrackDevice  too.

But how does it all fit in java syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most language which support lambda, it could support eta-conversion.

E.g.

```
x => Math.abs(x) is a lambda, it could be shorted as Math.abs
```

Java8 also support it, but it did not use `Math.abs`, it use `Math::abs`.

So, here `this::onDeviceList` is just a lambda (it just be supported from java8).

When the actor receive the variable `msg` with the type `RequestDeviceList`, it will call `this::onDeviceList(msg)` internal. Here, as `this::onDeviceList` is a lambda, so actor can directly call this lambada and set parameter(`'msg'`) when call this lambda function (lambda as function parameter, so you did not see parameter here)

In a word, you need to be familiar with java8's lambda support to know how it fits in java syntax.